# Plotting a directed contour with self-intersections

Tags: plotting, graphics, interpolation

I have an ordered sequence of points along a closed directed planar contour with self-intersections. I need to find a continuous curve interpolating those points and plot it, with small arrowheads showing its direction (preferably, placed at equal intervals along the curve), and color-fill enclosed regions having an odd winding number. Below is a picture I drew manually to explain the idea (it should be more smooth than that). How can I do this in *Mathematica*?
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Something to get you started:

```
SeedRandom[10]
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {8, 2}];

int = Interpolation[Thread@{N@Subdivide[0, 1, 8], Append[#, First@#] &@pts}, PeriodicInterpolation -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 100];
line = FirstCase[ParametricPlot[int[x], {x, 0, 1}], _Line, Line@{}, All];
Graphics[
 {
  LightGray,
  FilledCurve@line,
  Black,
  Thick,
  Arrowheads@Append[0]@Table[0.05, 10],
  Arrow@JoinedCurve@line,
  Red,
  AbsolutePointSize@5,
  Point@pts
  }
 ]
```

[image]

The main idea is to use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) with [`PeriodicInterpolation->True`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PeriodicInterpolation.html) and a high [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) to get the boundary. The [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) is then sampled with the help of [`ParametericPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametericPlot.html) to get a smooth look without just blindly sampling hundereds of times.

Finally, the image is built using [`Arrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html) and [`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) for the perimeter, and [`FilledCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html) for the shading.